# Inherit Class with constructors in visual basic

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class, inheritance, constructor

I am working on a wpf application using Visual Basic and I want to make use of the inherit function to create my custom classes. I have made a dummy project just to make my problem clear to everyone.

I want to inherit properties from my parent class to my child class. Please pay attention to the child class. My problem is, in the way that my code is written;

-When I want to call the child class in my mainwindow behind code, I cannot assign values to all of the inhereted properties of the child class, it only allows me to assing values to the new properties that are in the child class as shown below.

```
Dim ChildClass As New ChildClass(var5, var6)'<---Unable to assing values to the rest of the inherited properties
```

-Also within the child class I am unable to assing fields to the inhereted properties, and there you will see this weird

```
MyBase.New(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

which basically prevents me from controlling the values of the inhereted properties.

However as you can see at the mainwindow behind code I am able to read and use all 6 properties of the child class(inhereted and new ones),but with the not desirable values for the inhereted ones.

**What I would like is to be able to assing values to all the 6 properties when I am calling the child class from my mainwindow behind code.**

I guess all the constructors definitions are connected to this issue so if you could try to run my program and propose a solution would be great!

My MainWindow XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="InheritClassExample" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="val1" Text="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="val2" Text="2"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="val3" Text="3"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="val4" Text="4"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="val5" Text="5"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="val6" Text="6"></TextBox>
        <Button Margin="50" Click="Button_Click">GO!</Button>
        <WrapPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBox Name="ParentClassBox" Width="auto"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Name="ChildClassBox" Width="auto"></TextBox>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

The code behind my MainWindow:

```
 Imports DummyInheritExample.Utilities

Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        'assign the values from my input window to varriables withing this sub
        Dim var1 As Double = val1.Text
        Dim var2 As Double = val2.Text
        Dim var3 As Double = val3.Text
        Dim var4 As Double = val4.Text
        Dim var5 As Double = val5.Text
        Dim var6 As Double = val6.Text

        'calling the parent class

        Dim parentClass As New ParentClass(var1, var2, var3, var4)
        ParentClassBox.Text = "The numerical valeus in the ParentClass are :" + parentClass.field1.ToString + parentClass.field2.ToString + parentClass.field3.ToString + parentClass.field4.ToString

        Dim ChildClass As New ChildClass(var5, var6)'<---Unable to assing values to the rest of the inherited properties
        ChildClassBox.Text = "The numerical valeus in the ChildClass are :" + ChildClass.field1.ToString + ChildClass.field2.ToString + ChildClass.field3.ToString + ChildClass.field4.ToString + ChildClass.field5.ToString + ChildClass.field6.ToString

    End Sub
End Class
```

The code of my Parent Class:

```
Namespace Utilities
    Public Class ParentClass

        Sub New(_field1 As Double, _field2 As Double, _field3 As Double, _field4 As Double)
            field1 = _field1
            field2 = _field2
            field3 = _field3
            field4 = _field4
        End Sub


        Private _field1 As Double

        Public Property field1() As Double
            Get
                Return _field1
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                _field1 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _field2 As Double
        Public Property field2() As Double
            Get
                Return _field2
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                _field2 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _field3 As Double
        Public Property field3() As Double
            Get
                Return _field3
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                _field3 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _field4 As Double
        Public Property field4() As Double
            Get
                Return _field4
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                _field4 = value
            End Set
        End Property


    End Class
End Namespace
```

The code of my Child Class:

```
Namespace Utilities
    Public Class ChildClass
        Inherits ParentClass

        Sub New(_field5 As Double, _field6 As Double)
            MyBase.New(1, 1, 1, 1) ' here visual basic asked me to enter this statment
            field5 = _field5
            field6 = _field6
        End Sub


        Private _field5 As Double
        Public Property field5() As Double
            Get
                Return _field5
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                _field5 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _field6 As Double
        Public Property field6() As Double
            Get
                Return _field6
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                _field6 = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Dim test As Double = field1



    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you meant - Add a constructor in Child class with all fields.

```
Sub New(_field1 As Double, _field2 As Double, _field3 As Double, _field4 As Double, _field5 As Double, _field6 As Double)
            MyBase.New(_field1, _field2, _field3, _field4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks Priya thank you, thats correct. I solved my problem and the constructor now looks like this:

```
Sub New(ByVal _field1 As Double, _field2 As Double, ByVal _field3 As Double, _field4 As Double, ByVal _field5 As Double, _field6 As Double)
    MyBase.New(_field1, _field2, _field3, _field4)
    Me.field5 = _field5
    Me.field6 = _field6

End Sub
```